# Functional Square Root of $1-x^3$

Tags: functions, functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

I'm completely stuck with the problem of finding such a **continuous** function $f$ that

$
f(f(x)) = 1 - x^3
$

or **prove that it doesn't exist**.

After some calculations I tend to the second case - continuous function with such property can not exist.
Does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: You obviously don't plan to show us those calculations, or to tell us why anybody should care.

Comment: $1-x^3$ is decreasing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(f(x)) = 1-x^3$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Note that $f$ is injective, since
\begin{align*}
&f(x) = f(y)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f(f(x))=f(f(y))\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1-x^3 = 1-y^3\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^3=y^3\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x=y\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Since $f$ is injective and continuous, it follows that $f$ is strictly monotonic.

If $f$ is strictly increasing, then
\begin{align*}
&x < y\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f(x) < f(y)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f(f(x)) < f(f(y))\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1-x^3 < 1-y^3\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^3 > y^3\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x > y\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.

If $f$ is strictly decreasing, then
\begin{align*}
&x < y\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f(x) > f(y)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f(f(x)) < f(f(y))\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1-x^3 < 1-y^3\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^3 > y^3\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x > y\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.

Hence, no such function $f$ exists.